# Check if item in list is existing

Tags: python, postgresql

I have list of UUIDs (block_list) and want to check if one specific UUID is listed in that list.

```py
list(block_list)

Out[41]: 
[ ('f779e98c-a541-4ae2-afcb-b0da2e5bee24',),
 ('a005bc7b-c06d-48bf-8259-757d52c70330',),
 ('8af278b1-089e-40e9-a57d-856efe336c26',)]
```

Why is that giving me a false?

'8af278b1-089e-40e9-a57d-856efe336c26' in block_list
Answer: False

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Because you don't have UUIDs a list, you have UUIDs in tuples in a list: SQL queries always return tuples even when retrieving a single datum.

Comment: `('8af278b1-089e-40e9-a57d-856efe336c26',) in [ ('f779e98c-a541-4ae2-afcb-b0da2e5bee24',),
 ('a005bc7b-c06d-48bf-8259-757d52c70330',),
 ('8af278b1-089e-40e9-a57d-856efe336c26',)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a string inside a tuple, do not pass the raw string to see if it's in the list. Here is a simple function that can do it for you by passing a raw string and nesting it inside a tuple with a trailing comma:

```py
def check_string(string):
    if ((string, ) in my_list):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Because '8af278b1-089e-40e9-a57d-856efe336c26' is a string but your list consists of tuples

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is false because you are checking if a string is in a list. But your list is a list of the tuples. So you have to check if any particular tuple is in the list.

So instead you need following codes:

```
('8af278b1-089e-40e9-a57d-856efe336c26') in block_list
```

Now the output will be True